# Why isn't my perceptron having the expected costs?

Tags: python, implementation, linear-regression, perceptron

I want to implement a single perceptron for linear regression using the following formulas:

[image: formulas]

The input data for the first case is one column `(x(392, 1); y(392, 1))` and for the second case is `(x(392, 7); y(392, 1))`. The `NaN` values have been removed and `x` values have been standardized `x-x.mean()/x.std()`

This is my Python implementation:

```
class LinearRegression(object):


    def __init__(self, x, y, n_iter):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.n_iter = n_iter
        self.cost_iteration = []
        # Initializing model parameters (w, b) to zeros
        self.weights = np.zeros((1, self.x.shape[1]))   # w: weights
        self.biases  = np.zeros((1, 1))                 # b: bias 

    def feedforward(self):
        # return the feedforward value for x
        #self.weights, self.biases = self.update_params()
        z = self.x @ self.weights.T  + self.biases
        return z
    
    def loss(self):
      # return the loss value for given x and y
      z = self.feedforward() 
      loss = self.y-z
      cost = np.sum(loss**2)/self.y.shape[0]
      return loss, cost 

    def backpropagation(self):
      # return the derivatives with respect to weight matrix and biases
      loss, cost  = self.loss()
      db = -2*np.sum(loss)/self.y.shape[0]                    # dJ/db
      dw = -2*np.dot(self.x.T, loss)/self.y.shape[0]          # dJ/dw
      return dw, db   
    
    def update_params(self):
      # update weights and biases based on the output
      dw, db = self.backpropagation()
      self.weights -= dw.T
      self.biases  -= db
      return self.weights, self.biases
    
    def fit(self):
      # fit method for the training data
      for iter in range(self.n_iter):
        self.update_params()
        print(self.biases)
        l, c = self.loss()
        self.cost_iteration.append (c)
      return self.cost_iteration
```

The final cost should be approximately 23.9 and 11.6 for the two models, respectively. But I can't figure out why it's not the case when I use my code.

Comment: Hello. Could you please put your **specific** question in the title?

Comment: I am not sure how to formulate the question correctly. But I think the problem is my implementation of the loss and update methods. I think they are wrong based on the resulting cost.

Comment: Ok, I tried to give a more descriptive title to your post. Please, make sure that it's consistent with what you were asking. How do you know that the cost should approximately be 23.9 and 11.6?

Comment: It is said at the end of the document (from which I took the screenshot above).